Save lopping results in r as data.frame
I have a daily rainfall time series in several rain gauges (in columns) and calculate some annual indices, such as the annual Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI). I used looping to generate the SPI results by year, for each rain gauge and I need to save the results in a data frame or another similar alternative. how could I save it?
library(precintcon)
library(reshape2)
library(plyr)

#Creating a data.frame exemple using precintcon package
df=melt(daily,id = c("year","month"))
df$value2=df$value;df$value3=df$value;df$value4=df$value
colnames(df) <- c('year','month','day','RainGaue1','RainGaue2','RainGaue3','RainGaue4') 
head(df)

#Looping
ncol(df)
nproc = 4
cont = 1
#Data.frame with results
dfr = data.frame(variavel = character(nproc), 
                 SPI = numeric(nproc),
                 stringsAsFactors = F)
# i = 2
for (i in 2:5) {
  
  print(i) 
  df2<-df[,-c(2,3)]#
  nome.var=colnames(df2[i])
  variavela = nome.var[1]
  dfr$variavel[cont] = variavela
  
  TIM = TIM[,c(1,2,i)]
  TIM = na.omit(TIM)
  names(TIM) = c("Year","Month","Cd")
  head(TIM)
  df2=TIM
   
  names(df2)[1] <- "year"
  names(df2)[2] <- "month"
  names(df2)[3] <- "precipitation"
  
  df2=as.monthly(df2)
  head(df2)
  
  # SPI calculation - how to save it for all raingauges?
  SPI=spi.per.year(df2, period = 12);SPI
  #I want to save the results for the rain gauges that are in the columns, #in the same 
  #spreadsheet (see example below).
  
cont = cont + 1
  
library(writexl)
write_xlsx(dfr, "SPI.xlsx")#this doesn't work!
}



Example of the table I want to save:


(Unsolicited advice: move on from plyr, which has been retired for a number of years, to dplyr and tidyr, which have more consistent syntax, better performance, better support, and more capabilities.)

The loop could be replaced with library(dplyr); df |>  summarize(across(starts_with("Rain"), \(x) mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)), .by = year). That will take df, and summarize across all columns named "Rain*" with the annual mean value, ignoring NAs.

Even better, make your data tidy (eg columns year month gauge rainfall or similar) for easier interface with the tidyverse…
